# How can I efficiently load this kind of ASCII files with python?

Tags: python, numpy, io

I have big fortran-generated ASCII files formatted like this:

```
x y z  num_line index
1 float
2 float
...
num_line float
x2 y2 z2 num_line2 index2
1 float
2 float
...
num_line2 float
...
```

The number of blocks can go up to thousands and the number of lines whithin each block to hundreds.

Let's give an example of what I get:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0  4 0
1 0.5
2 0.9
3 0.4
4 0.1
0.0 0.0 1.0  4 1
1 0.2
2 0.2
3 0.4
4 0.9
0.0 1.0 2.0  5 2
1 0.7
2 0.6
3 0.9
4 0.2
5 0.7
```

And what I want from that (as a numpy matrix):

```
0.5 0.2 0.7
0.9 0.2 0.6
0.4 0.4 0.9
0.1 0.9 0.2
nan nan 0.7
```

Of course, I can use:

```
my_mat = []
with open("myfile", "r") as f_in:
    niter = int(f_in.readline().split()[3])
    while niter:
        curr_vect = zeros(niter)
        for i in xrange(niter):
            curr_vect[i] = float(f_in.readline().split()[1])
        my_mat.append(curr_vect)
        line = f_in.readline()
        if line is not None:
            niter = int(line.split()[3])
        else:
            niter = False
my_mat = array(my_mat)
```

The problem is this is not really efficient and too much complicated for what it is. I already know about numpy's `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` but they do not seem to apply there.

I'm looking for something faster and much more readable. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Please forgive me, my question was not complete and some of you lost his time because of me. Here is a real example of such a block:

```
3.571428571429E-02 3.571428571429E-02-3.571428571429E-02         1   35  
       1 -0.493775207966779     
       2  0.370269037864060     
       3  0.382332033744703     
       4  0.382332033744703     
       5  0.575515346181205     
       6  0.575515346181216     
       7  0.575562530624028     
       8  0.639458035564442     
       9  0.948445367602052     
      10  0.948445367602052     
      11  0.975303238888803     
      12   1.20634795229899     
      13   1.21972845646758     
      14   1.21972845646759     
      15   1.52659950368213     
      16   2.07381346028515     
      17   2.07629743909555     
      18   2.07629743909555     
      19   2.15941179949552     
      20   2.15941179949552     
      21   2.30814240005132     
      22   2.30814240005133     
      23   2.31322868361483     
      24   2.53625115348660     
      25   2.55301153157825     
      26   2.55301153157826     
      27   2.97152031842301     
      28   2.98866790318661     
      29   2.98866790318662     
      30   3.24757159459268     
      31   3.27186643004142     
      32   3.27186643004143     
      33   3.37632477135298     
      34   3.37632477135299     
      35   3.55393884607834
```

Comment: I don't see a easy and clean way to do this other than straight up code a reader specific to that format like you did. I assume you need to process this file multiple times? Then I would advise you to read this file once with the method you mentioned above and just convert it to a file structure that's easy for python or numpy to read. If the file changes, you might want to consider changing the output format in fortran (if you have access to that code).

Comment: Yes, `pytables` will gladly do that. The problem is that I have a lot of files formatted this way... I also have a lot of files formatted in similar, yet not identical ways. Let's say I've been writing this kind of programs for years for csv tables before I heard of loadtxt... Which is a shame.

Comment: No, some persons might have tried something (without having it published yet) with the same assumptions as tiago. I've not answered to you yet. I will. I'm really interested by the way you solved this and I'd like to experiment a bit before commenting it. :)

Comment: @Gael, in your real example you have two numbers (one negative) without a space separating them. This will be a really annoying problem to get around, and one must use fixed spacing to read the columns.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Fortran Powa! Then I should replace splits by hard-coded column ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby,izip_longest

def f1(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return np.matrix(list(izip_longest(
               *(map(lambda x: float(x[1]),v)
               for k,v in groupby(map(str.split,f),
               key=lambda x: len(x) == 2) if k),
               fillvalue=np.nan)))
d1('testfile')
```

*out:*

```
matrix([[ 0.5,  0.2,  0.7],
        [ 0.9,  0.2,  0.6],
        [ 0.4,  0.4,  0.9],
        [ 0.1,  0.9,  0.2],
        [ nan,  nan,  0.7]])
```

*EDIT:*

As for the performance, I tested it against the `np.genfromtxt` solution *@TheodrosZelleke* and it seems to be about five times faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy.genfromtxt:

1. read **one** column, delimeted by **linebreak** `\n`
2. provide a custom converter function

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

# your data from above as string
raw = '''0.0 0.0 0.0  4 0
1 0.5
...
5 0.7
'''
```

here's the converter:

```
def custom_converter(line):
    token = line.split()
    if len(token) == 2:
        return float(token[1])
    else:
        return np.NaN
```

load the data:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(raw),
                     delimiter='\n',
                     converters={0: custom_converter})

print data
```

which prints:

```
[ nan  0.5  0.9  0.4  0.1  nan  0.2  0.2  0.4  0.9  nan  0.7  0.6  0.9  0.2
  0.7]
```

Now you build up the final data structure:

```
delims, = np.where(np.isnan(data))
max_block = np.max(np.diff(delims))
nblocks = delims.size
final_data = np.empty([max_block, nblocks]) + np.NaN

delims = delims.tolist()
delims.append(data.size)
low = delims[0] + 1
for i, up in enumerate(delims[1:]):
    final_data[0: up-low , i] = data[low:up]
    low = up + 1

print final_data
```

which prints

```
[[ 0.5  0.2  0.7]
 [ 0.9  0.2  0.6]
 [ 0.4  0.4  0.9]
 [ 0.1  0.9  0.2]
 [ nan  nan  0.7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would've been a lot faster if you made sure each block had the same number of lines (even if filled with zeros). That way you could just reshape an array read with `loadtxt`. But given that limitation, here's an example that might be a bit faster:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("myfile", usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)
nx = np.sum(data[0] == 0)
ny = np.max(data[0])
my_mat = np.empty((nx, ny), dtype='d')
my_mat[:] = np.nan   # if you really want to populate it with NaNs for missing
tr_ind = data[0, list(np.nonzero(np.diff(data[0]) < 0)[0]) + [-1]].astype('i')
buf = np.squeeze(data[1, np.nonzero(data[0])])

idx = 0
for i in range(nx):
    my_mat[i, :tr_ind[i]] = buf[idx : idx + tr_ind[i]]
    idx += tr_ind[i]
```

And you can check the result:

```
>>> print my_mat.T
array([[ 0.5,  0.2,  0.7],
       [ 0.9,  0.2,  0.6],
       [ 0.4,  0.4,  0.9],
       [ 0.1,  0.9,  0.2],
       [ nan,  nan,  0.7]])
```

**UPDATE:** as pointed out by TheodrosZelleke, the above solution fails when `x2` (first column) is non-zero. I didn't notice this the first time. Here is an update to get around that:

```
# this will give a conversion warning because column number varies
blk_sizes = np.genfromtxt("myfile", invalid_raise=False, usecols=(-2,))

nx = blk_sizes.size
ny = np.max(blk_sizes)

data = np.loadtxt("myfile", usecols=(1,))
my_mat = np.empty((nx, ny), dtype='d')
my_mat[:] = np.nan

idx = 1
for i in range(nx):
    my_mat[i, :blk_sizes[i]] = data[idx : idx + blk_sizes[i]]
    idx += blk_sizes[i] + 1
```

(And then take `my_mat.T`.)

Comment: -1) Sorry, but your algorithm depends on the fact that the rows to be excluded start with a `0.`. Although the OP did not state explicitly that this is not the case, one might guess that these lines (which contain x, y, z coordinates) will have other values for x. I claim it is impossible to provide a solution by just looking at the first two columns -- you need to look at the token count on each line

Comment: You are correct. I don't have time right now, but it's not hard to change the algorithm to avoid the zeros. You can always look at the derivative of the first column (even though you'll need some switch for some of the cases), or find a way to extract those numbers by looking at other columns. My solution was not meant to be a complete answer but a starting point.

Comment: Its a starting point to nowhere -- this problem requires an answer which does not imply any assumptions about the numerical value of the first two columns -- you cannot work with any kind of derivative... you need to look at the token count on each line

Comment: There is enough information in the first two columns to determine when it jumps to another block. Whether you believe it or not is of no consequence.

Comment: It would have been faster if the data were saved in HDF5 directly but it's not. I can tweak my version of the fortran program but I can't do it for the others. BTW, I gave you a real example of a block. zeros were easier to reach than other numbers... Sorry for that. And I have to agree on what Theodros wrote: relying on the data to infer the data structure does not seem to be a good idea. The next x in the example I just added CAN be equal to 3.6E01. That would lead to unspotable bugs. Nevertheless, thanks for your answer: I did not consider this approach and I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: How do you determine the next block if the first column reads: `block row; 1; 2; 1; 1; ...`. This is not unambiguous. You would probably need to look to the next element, and so on... I am probably inclined to agree with you that in principle the information can be retrieved from the first column... but this approach is more difficult than useful.